# XConnect Serilog Replacement

Tags: xconnect, logging

Our in house shop uses a homegrown logging library to centralize all of our application logs for reporting, searching, and support. XConnect comes equip with the Serilog out of box. Is there a way to rather replace it fully with our in house solution or to supplement our logs into the same stream built out in the sc.Serilog.xml so that both loggers can run.

**Path to config:** `[Solution]\App_data\Config\Sitecore\CoreServices\sc.Serilog.xml`

I believe this is the same for all xConnect sites and services so one change should be able to replace all of the references in our scaled solution.

Thanks,
Tyler

Comment: Do you need the logged data immediately? Or dumping them to your internal logging system later would be an option for you?

Comment: The logs we use in house get written to a folder on the server. There's a windows service responsible for picking up the file and processing the information. So really would just be replacing the flat file with a different flat file. We have enough control to run an in between class to match any methods that the Sitecore would be looking to use.

Comment: I had the same thoughts but wanted to clarify with you as it was not stated in your question what is your in house logging functionality :-)

Comment: I wrote a blogpost how to use other serilog here: https://sitecoreclimber.wordpress.com/2020/01/10/view-sitecore-xconnect-logs-in-log2console/ please have a look there